# Why do I need to add @Component when I have to schedule the task in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I didn't understand the proper use of @Componenet, @Configuration,@Bean annotation.
I want to run one method in every 60 seconds.Please check the below code. If I don't give @Component annotation then it doesn't run. so What is the use of @Component in this context?

```
    @EnableScheduling
    public class SchedulingProjectApplication {

    private static final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulingProjectApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 6000)
    public void r()
    {
        log.info("Start- main-job");
        log.info("stop-main-job");
    }

    }
```

Comment: This is to tell spring to scan this file while booting up. Only when it has one of the spring annotations,Spring scans that file. And only when it scans, it can read that you have a Scheduler configured and will do scheduling

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this piece of code:

1. Your Spring Boot application is not flagged with `@SpringBootApplication` (or `@EnableAutoConfiguration`). As a result, the auto-configuration will not kick in at all (Spring Boot will start your app but won't do anything with it besides basic stuff  such as env preparation, etc). It's perfectly fine in certains cases but that isn't probably what you want
2. You've flagged the run task directly on your app. It's ok for demo but it would be better to move that logic in its own class

So to answer your question: `SchedulingProjectApplication` is the root source of your app but it's just a simple POJO. There's nothing that instructs the container to process it. Usually the app is a `@Configuration` (you can use one of the `@EnableXYZ` on it, you can define additional beans, etc.

If you add `@SpringBootApplication` on your class, it will scan any `@Component` in the same package of your app (and all the sub-packages).

More details about code structure [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)

One basic/simple structure for you would be:

```
package com.example.foo;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And

```
package com.example.foo;

@Component
public class SchedulingLogger {

    private static final Logger log = 
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulingLogger.class);

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 6000)
    public void r()
    {
        log.info("Start- main-job");
        log.info("stop-main-job");
    }
}
```

There are other things that you should be aware with regards to configuration (such as [moving decisions outside of your `@SpringBootApplication` if you use slicing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M6/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-user-configuration)).

Comment: my main class is different.I have annotated @springBootApplication to my main class.

Comment: Why are you asking a question with not the code you're actually using then?